# Mods- please delete duplicate tags

Tags: discussion, tag, tag-mistakes

I find many tags redundant. I guess there have come into existence due to the difference in language of people.

#### Example

[nikah](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nikah) [marriage](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marriage) [wedding](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wedding) all mean the same

[wudu](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wudu) [ablution](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ablution) mean the same

[fasting](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fasting) [sawm](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sawm) mean the same

[ramadan](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ramadan) [ramazan](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ramazan) mean the same

[rouh](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rouh) [soul](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soul) mean the same

I see some created in error I guess [sciense](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sciense)

May be they can be made tag-synonymous. But surely such cases needs to taken care of.

Comment: Some of these are already synonyms.

Comment: `[science]` seems fairly reasonable to me. Reconciling scientific findings with religious teachings is a struggle many people of faith face daily. It is not a binary decision; science and faith can coexist even if they (seemingly) contradict one another.

Comment: @aarthi `[sciense]` is a bit less defensible (and a bit more susceptible to aggressive spellchecking)

Comment: @goldPseudo Ah ha! I stand (or sit, rather) corrected! :D

Answer (score 1):

Of the listed tags, the ones that have been actioned are as follows:

- [sawm](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sawm) and [fasting](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fasting) were already synonyms; I could merge them (and thus destroy one or the other) but given that both terms are likely to be used I feel it preferable to keep them as is.
- I have created a synonym for [ramazan](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ramazan); I was previously just destroying this tag whenever I saw it, since [ramadan](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ramadan) would pop up whenever anyone started typing it anyway, but it keeps cropping up.  As it seems a common variant spelling, might as well synonym it.
- [sciense](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sciense) has been merged into [science](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science).  Not bothering to synonymize what appears to be an obvious typo.

The remaining ones are not as clear-cut, and I would rather not use moderator abilities to synonymize and/or merge them without a proper community consensus (which, if still desired, should each be discussed in their own separate questions).  My concerns follow:

- While [rouh](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rouh) *could* be used for [soul](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soul), it could also be used to refer to Jibril instead; hardly a clear synonym.
- Are [marriage](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marriage) and [wedding](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wedding) really the same thing?  One refers to the institution of marriage itself, whereas the other refers to the festival in which one is married.  Closely-related, yes, but not exact synonyms.  And if they *are* determined to be different, which one should [nikah](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nikah) be synonymed to?
- [ablution](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ablution) could refer to either [wudu](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wudu) or [ghusl](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ghusl).  Should [wudu](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wudu) and [ghusl](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ghusl) be synonyms, since they're not really the same thing?  If not, which one would [ablution](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ablution) synonym to?